# Can RemoteEvents be two way?

Tags: roblox

For example, would these scripts work, hang, or possibly give an error?

(In a script)

```
RemoteEvent = game:GetService("ReplicatedStorage"):WaitForChild("RemoteEvent")

RemoteEvent:FireClient()
RemoteEvent.onServerEvent:Wait()
print("Hello World")
```

(In a LocalScript)

```
RemoteEvent = game:GetService("ReplicatedStorage"):WaitForChild("RemoteEvent")

RemoteEvent.onClientEvent:Wait()
RemoteEvent:FireServer()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To simply answer your question, RemoteEvents do work both ways. The same event can be used from client-to-server as server-to-client.

Your example, as-is, will likely have some timing issues.
The server will start, fire on all zero clients, then wait for a client to send the signal back.
At some time later, a client will join and then wait for the server signal (which has already happened) and get stuck.

Depending on your desired logic, you could wait to execute the code when a player joins the game :

```
-- server Script
local PlayerService = game:GetService("Players")
local ReplicatedStorage = game:GetService("ReplicatedStorage")
local RemoteEvent = ReplicatedStorage.RemoteEvent

PlayerService.PlayerAdded:Connect( function(player)
    -- Wait() will fire for any player that sends up the signal, so make sure that we know which player sent it
    -- instead, connect to the signal to make sure we're listening to the right player
    RemoteEvent.OnServerEvent:Connect( function(clientPlayer)
        if clientPlayer.Name == player.Name then

            print("Hello World", player.Name)

            -- pass some data from the server to the client
            RemoteEvent:FireClient( player, 1, 2, 3)
        end)
    end)
end)
```

Then in your client...

```
-- LocalScript in PlayerScripts
local ReplicatedStorage = game:GetService("ReplicatedStorage")
local RemoteEvent = ReplicatedStorage.RemoteEvent

-- since there's no telling when this event will fire, tell the server that we've loaded!
RemoteEvent:FireServer()

-- wait for the server to respond and give us some data
local connection
connection = RemoteEvent.OnClientEvent:Connect( function(a, b, c)
    print("got data from server : ", a, b, c)

    -- disconnect so this event only fires once
    connection:Disconnect()
end)
```

Answer (score 1):

I would like to add to Kylaaa's answer and in response to your code example that if your intention is to wait for a response from the client, you can also invoke a RemoteFunction instead of firing an event and waiting for an event to come back to you. Something like this:

Script:

```
game.Players.PlayerAdded:Connect(function(plr)
    local response = game.ReplicatedStorage.RemoteFunction:InvokeClient(plr, "Hello")
    print("Client said: " .. response)  
end)
```

LocalScript:

```
game.ReplicatedStorage.RemoteFunction.OnClientInvoke = function(text)
    print ("Server said: " .. text)
    return "Hi"
end
```

PS. A RemoteFunction also works both ways.